# Is it possible to import an Ableton sample file .adv into the Launchpad app (by Ampify)?

Tags: beginner, ableton-live, samples

I made a sample file in Ableton and would like to put it in the launchpad app. Is there any easy way to do this? I would like to be able to choose which sample thing to assign to each button.

I'm new to this, as you can probably tell.